# Combining grep flags

Tags: grep, flags

I'm trying to find lines that start with 'query' or the following sign: '>' but I don't know how to do this.

If this is the dataset:

```
query=345
query=4565
brink=980
>ehlhdhdk
>blonk
```

I want to only preserve the lines 1,2,4 and 5.
I have tried: `grep -e 'query=' filename.txt||grep -F '>' filename.txt > newfile.txt`

and:
`cat filename.txt | grep -e 'query='||grep -F '>' > newfile.txt`.
But these do not work and they do not output the newfile.txt and instead they just output into the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multiple patterns with option `-e`:

```
grep -e '^>' -e '^query' file
```

Output:

```
query=345
query=4565
>ehlhdhdk
>blonk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
grep -E '^(query|>)' filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(query|>)`  - a capturing group that matches either

  - `query` - `query`
  - `|` - or
  - `>` - a `>` char.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/zHYtFM):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='query=345
query=4565
brink=980
>ehlhdhdk
>blonk'
grep -E '^(query|>)' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
query=345
query=4565
>ehlhdhdk
>blonk
```